# Proof that $\lnot F(A_0, ... A_n) \sim F'(\lnot A_0, ... ,\lnot A_n)$

Tags: logic, induction

I would like to proof that if $F := F(A_0, ... , A_n)$ and $F'$ be a formula that is created from $F$ in that

$A_i$ in $F$ is replaced by $\lnot A_i$,

$\land$ in $F$ is replaced by $\lor$,

$\lor$ in $F$ is replaced by $\land$,

$\bot$ in $F$ is replaced by $\top$,

$\top$ in $F$ is replaced by $\bot$.

then $\lnot F(A_0, ... A_n) \sim F'(\lnot A_0, ... ,\lnot A_n)$

I want to use structural induction, but seem to fail at some point.

base case: Let $F$ be a formula with only one propositional variable $F(A_0) = A_0$. Then $F'(\lnot A_0) = \lnot A_0 = \lnot F$ and hence $\lnot F(A_0) \sim F(A_0)$.

IH: It holds for a propositional formula $F$, without  $\leftrightarrow$ and $\rightarrow$ that $\lnot F(A_0, ... A_n) \sim F'(\lnot A_0, ... ,\lnot A_n)$

IS: (i) Let $F(A_0, ... , A_n) = (F' \land G'$), where $F'$ and $G'$ are propositional formulas. After IV, we obtain $F^{\star} \sim \lnot F'$ and $F^{\star} \sim \lnot G'$.

It is according to Def. $F^{\star}(\lnot A_0, ..., \lnot A_n) = (F'^{\star}(\lnot A_0, ... , \lnot A_n) \lor G'^{\star}(\lnot A_0, ..., \lnot A_n)) \stackrel{\text{IH}}{\Longleftrightarrow} (\lnot F' \lor \lnot G') \stackrel{\text{DM}}{\Longleftrightarrow} \lnot (F' \land G') = \lnot F$

(ii) Now let $F = (F' \lor G')$. Then by the definition of $F^{\star}$.

$F^{\star} = (F'^{\star} \land G'^{\star}) \stackrel{\text{IH}}{\Longleftrightarrow} (\lnot F \land \lnot G) \stackrel{\text{DM}}{\Longleftrightarrow} \lnot ( F \lor G) = \lnot F$

(ii) Let $F = \lnot F'$. Then according to the def. of $F^{\star}$.

$F^{\star} = \lnot F'^{\star} \stackrel{\text{IH}}{\Longleftrightarrow} \lnot ( \lnot F') = \lnot F$

$\textbf{EDIT}$

IS: (i) Let $F(A_0, ... , A_n) = (\psi_1 \land \psi_2$), with $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ being propositional formulas. By IH $\psi_1^{\star} \sim \lnot \psi_1$ and $\psi_2^{\star} \sim \lnot \psi_2$.

From the Definition of $F^{\star}(\lnot A_0, ..., \lnot A_n) = (\psi_1^{\star} \lor \psi_2^{\star}) \stackrel{\text{IV}}{\Longleftrightarrow} (\lnot \psi_1 \lor \lnot \psi_2) \stackrel{\text{DM}}{\Longleftrightarrow} \lnot (\psi_1 \land \psi_2) = \lnot F$

(ii) Let $F = (\psi_1 \lor \psi_2)$. With the Definition of $F^{\star}$

$F^{\star} = (\psi_1^{\star} \land \psi_2^{\star}) \stackrel{\text{IV}}{\Longleftrightarrow} (\lnot \psi_1 \land \lnot \psi_2) \stackrel{\text{DM}}{\Longleftrightarrow} \lnot ( \psi_1 \lor \psi_2) = \lnot F$

(ii) Let $F = \lnot \psi_1$. With the Definition of $F^{\star}$

$F^{\star} = \lnot \psi_1^{\star} \stackrel{\text{IV}}{\Longleftrightarrow} \lnot ( \lnot \psi_1) = \lnot F$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the Inductive Step you are still only referring to atomic variables $A$. Instead, you need to generalize that to any formula. In fact, the whole problem statement that you presented is formulated in terms of atomic statements, but I am sure that you are supposed to generalize this. That is, the overall problem is to show that:

$$\lnot \phi \sim (\lnot \phi)'$$

where $\phi = F(A_0, ... A_n))$ is any propositional logic formula that only contains $\neg, \land, \lor, \bot, and \top$ and atomic variables $A_0, ... A_n$

As such, your inductive base is still correct, but for the inductive step, you need to consider some arbitrary (but not-atomic) formula $\phi$, and where by the inductive hypothesis you can assume that no matter whether $\phi = \neg \phi_0$,  $\phi = \phi_1 \land \phi_2$, or $\phi = \phi_1 \lor \phi_2$, it is the case that:

$$\lnot \phi_i \sim (\lnot \phi_i)'$$

So using that as the IH, you now need to show that:

$$\lnot \phi \sim (\lnot \phi)'$$

Comment: Since it is $\sim$, does the direction matter? i.e. can I start with either $\lnot F$ or $F'$ to arrive at $F'$ or $\lnot F$ respectively

Comment: @F.V. Correct, you can go either way :)

Comment: I have edited the IS, at least I tried :D

Comment: @F.V. First: you should really use an EDITED section in your post, but underneath your original text to show how you responded to my comments ... otherwise my comments no longer make sense, and anyone trying to follow the same learning process will be lost.  Second:  it's still not right: what you state as the IH is what you need to show. Rather, for the IH use $\neg F \sim F'$ and $\neg G \sim G'$

Comment: @F.V.  But yes, you made good progress!

Comment: Sorry for the non editing. I will make another edit post and try to clean up a bit and apply your comment!

Comment: @F.V. No worries! Just something to think abut for future posts. And you're getting close! :)

Comment: I have made the edit. Btw what about $\top$ and $\bot$? Must they be included aswell

Comment: Yes, good catch about the $\bot$ and $\top$ ... you can include those in the base case. The step is for creating a larger formula out of a smaller one, i.e. when you apply $\neg$, $\land$, or $\lor$.   I am a little unclear what your $F^*$ is ... is that just $F'$ or something different?

Comment: In the Edit I have replaced $F'$ and $G'$ with $\psi$. $F^*$ is the same in both, the edited and non-edited part

Comment: @F.V. Looks good to me! Just need to add $\bot$ and $\top$ to the base case